# Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65552 bytes) with GoDaddy shared hosting

Tags: php, drupal, settings, ini

I am facing an Allowed Memory Issue in my Drupal site.

I've tried:

1. Created a phpinfo.php file added the below code `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and executed.

   Result :

   > Configuration File (php.ini) Path : /usr/local/lib
   >
   > Loaded Configuration File : /usr/local/lib/php.ini

   I cloned the php.ini file from the above path and renamed to php5.ini and pushed to the Drupal folder. After the code push I also see the same path in phpinfo file. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.
2. .htaccess file

   `<IfModule mod_php5.c>`

   I added this code [ php_flag memory_limit 64M ]
3. settings.php

   ```
   // Increases the memory limit on admin pages to 512 MB
   $conf['page_memory_limit']['admin/structure/*'] = '1024M';
   $conf['page_memory_limit']['admin/config/*'] = '512M';
   $conf['page_memory_limit']['admin/people/*'] = '512M';
   $conf['page_memory_limit']['admin/modules/*'] = '1024M';
   $conf['page_memory_limit']['admin/content/node_export/*'] = '1024M';
   $conf['page_memory_limit']['admin/content/*'] = '1024M';
   $conf['page_memory_limit']['node/*'] = '1024M';
   $conf['page_memory_limit']['taxonomy/term/*'] = '1024M';
   $conf['page_memory_limit']['site/search/*'] = '1024M';
   ```

   Issue comes when ever I disable / enable module and also sometimes on page load.

URL : [Website Demo](http://aswtlocal.com/)

Comment: Have you restarted your apache server after changing php.ini file?

Comment: The message says that the 64MB you've allocated have been depleted. If that's expected then allocate more memory to PHP. (`php_flag memory_limit 128M`) If you don't expect PHP to be using that much memory then its most likely a bug with your code (stuck in a loop allocating a new something each iteration is a common cause for this).

Comment: @Krunal : Yes i did [ i killed process in godaddy server] and checked again same issue

Comment: @apokryfos : but first a fall i dont see the updated (php5.ini) in phpinfo output, then i can do some upgrade :-(

Comment: @yoo if you change the setting via `.htaccess` it won't appear as changed in `phpinfo` but it will still work. `phpinfo` shows settings written in php ini and loaded on php startup. `.htaccess` is a site specific override to those settings which is applied after the defaults have been loaded.